# Simple Quantum Mechanics question about the Free particle, (part1)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction

I am reading Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by David Griffiths and I am in Ch2 page 59. He starts out writing the time dependent Schrödinger equation and the solution for $\psi(x,t)$ for the free particle,

> $$\psi(x,t) = A e^{ik(x-(\hbar k/2m)t)} + B e^{-ik(x + (\hbar k/2m)t)}$$

Then he goes and says the following,

> Now, *any* function of $x$ and $t$ that depends on these variables in the special combination $x \pm vt$ (for some constant $v$) represents a wave of fixed profile, traveling in the $\pm x$-direction, at speed $v$.

What does this sentence mean?

Comment: Did you try plotting a representative function like this?

Comment: I'm trying to plot it on maple right now. I don't know what to specify the energies as, cause k = sqrt(2mE)/h_bar. Griffiths goes on and says that this wave function is NOT normalizable! So I'm confused.

Comment: [Another question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10101/help-me-to-visualize-this-wave-equation-in-time-to-which-direction-it-moves) that came shortly after this one explores the same math.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means there are many possible shapes for waves, not just pure sine waves.

For example,

$$\psi(x,t) = A\textrm{e}^{-k^2(x-vt)^2}$$

is a possible wavefunction.  It represents a Gaussian wave packet that travels down the x-axis in the positive direction at speed $v$.  The important part is that you can make the substitution $u = x-vt$ into $\psi$ and get a function of a single variable $u$.

So, start with any function $f$ of a single variable $u$.  Now make the substitution $u = x - vt$.  $f$ has now become a wave that travels down the x-axis at speed $v$ with some funky shape.

The mathematically-important thing is that such functions can be represented as a superposition of sinusoidals of continuously-varying frequencies all traveling in tandem down the x-axis (by "traveling" I mean "have phase velocity").  The sinusoidals that go with a given $f$ are found through [fourier analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis). This is important because the sinusoidals are the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian for a free particle.